# error in fetching the data from hbase

Tags: java, hbase

I have some specific data in an `HBase` table which has a large amount of data and 1000 regions.

When I am querying that data from shell, it takes 175 seconds to come using normal scan via column name. But the same thing I was trying to fetch using prefix filter in my java code, I am getting a timeout error.

Can anyone having idea why this thing happened and how I can get the data from my base table?

Please find the code below which i using

```
@Override
public Scan getScanForRowRange(List rowKeys, List columnList) {
    try {
        List rowrangeList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String rowKey : rowKeys) {
            byte[] startRow = Bytes.toBytes(rowKey);
            byte[] endRow = new byte[startRow.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(startRow, 0, endRow, 0, startRow.length);
            endRow[startRow.length] = (byte) 255;
            RowRange rowRange = new RowRange(startRow, true, endRow, false);
            rowrangeList.add(rowRange);
        }
        logger.info("row range size" + rowrangeList.size());
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        for (String columnName : columnList) {
            if (columnName.contains(ForesightConstants.COLON)) {
                String cellValues[] = columnName.split(ForesightConstants.COLON);
                scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(cellValues[ForesightConstants.ZERO]), Bytes.toBytes(cellValues[ForesightConstants.ONE]));
            }
        }
        scan.setFilter(new MultiRowRangeFilter(rowrangeList));
        scan.setCacheBlocks(true);
        scan.setCaching(10);
        return scan;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.info("Exception Inside @Method getScanForRowRange }", Utils.getStackTrace(e));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Could you add your code please?

Comment: Check if your shell has higher value of timeout set for property hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period, you can try to increase this value from default of 60000 to 180000 and try your java code

Comment: max i tried rowrange filter data is coming now but it takes lot's off time to come can you have the reason why it is happening